Scratch or crack in alloy headtube?
I was going over my bike in preparation for the season, and noticed these marks on both sides of the bottom side of head tube, near the weld to the down tube. I can't find any other marks on the bike that look like this. I'm concerned because this is a very high stress area. If it's damage it could result in catastrophic failure. On the other hand, the lines don't follow the welds like you might expect a crack to propagate. Most of them are in the middle of the weld itself. The inside of the head tube looks fine, but I suppose I wouldn't expect to see anything if the damage was just in the welds. I've haven't seen others like this after searching for photos of frame cracks. I've emailed the manufacturer but they have not responded yet. What do you think?



Not an expert, and diagnosing things from photos is notoriously hard.
First photo shows a crack in line with the side of a weld, which is where the weld would part company with the base metal if it were failing.
The second photo shows cracks nowhere near the edge of the weld - more characteristic of a paint crack.
If you're the original owner,dig out the paperwork to prove when the bike was bought, then take it back to the original shop you got it from.  The point is to notate the date when you informed them, so they can't weasel out by waiting till any warranty expires.
Another option is to interact with the frame maker, and find out the approved LBS in your area for that brand.
Some brands like Giant offer "lifetime" warranty on frames, some are 20/10/5/3/2/1 years.  And some legislation areas require a "good serviceable lifespan" even if the warranty has run out.   These warranties are normally only to the original purchaser or the person with the invoice/papers.

If its out of warranty, I'd chip away the paint in the area and try to deduce if its a crack in the weld.  Don't use sandpaper which could make a crack hard to find.
If it's just a crack in the paint, you're golden.  Repaint and ride it.
If it IS a crack in the weld, then repair is going to be hard/impossible - most aluminium alloy bikes are heat treated, and any welding tends to wreck the heat treating process.  Adding lots of weld and reinforcing plate might help, but the risk of warpage increases, and then you have a big weird bodge headset.
If you choose to ride it anyway, a steel bike would give lots of notice of failure.  An aluminium one tends to give some advance notice by feeling "noodly" and a carbon fibre bike gives the least notice, possibly none.
So if the bike starts feeling "weird" then stop immediately and inspect.

If you get to the point of scraping the paint off, go to the grocery and get some food dye. Drip some on the "crack", wait a bit, then wipe it off. Get a spray bottle and spritz a little water on the crack, and if it pulls more dye out, it came from a deeper crack which pulled in the dye via capillary action. Poor man's dye penetrant inspection. This can help determine if you have a crack even after sanding where the sanding marks might hide a crack.

Thanks for the feedback. The issue I have is that this is a custom frame from another country, there are no dealers or shops in my country that work with this manufacturer. It's well within the warranty period, it just may come down to deciding if it's worth it to ship the frame off for analysis by the manufacturer.

@Bob I suggest you contact the manufacturer by phone ASAP and see how they can help you.  Do make notes and get a followup by email for evidence.    Or if you just want a reason to buy another bike then do so while you continue to work this problem.  It won't be a quick fix and you need something to ride.
